# Android dependency 'com.airbnb.android:lottie' has different version for the compile (2.5.5)and runtime (2.5.6) classpath

Tags: react-native

I get this error when I try to run my react native app I manually changed the version to 2.5.6 but I got different error here below:
        [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.ApiLevelException: Invoke-customs ae only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)]

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexrchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Faile to process C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\lottie-2.5.6.aar\adddb5cebf38e2804a0cb857e5cf364\jars\classes.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug optin to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
147 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 146 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Here is my dependency

```
dependencies {


  compile project(':lottie-react-native')
  implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
  implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5') {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added an additional dependency to your dependencies.

Looking at the [example project](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/blob/master/example/android/app/build.gradle#L142) in the `lottie-react-native` repo  they only add the `compile project(':lottie-react-native')`

Here are the dependencies that they have for their example project. (Note that `compile` should be replaced with `implementation`)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lottie-react-native')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Notice that they do not have

```
implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5') {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

In any project that I have used Lottie I have never added

```
implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5')
```

If you remove that line, you should solve your problem.

---

#### Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)]

This error is caused by the fact that the Lottie dependency requires Java 8 bytecode. So to get it to work we need to enable desugaring in the `app/build.gradle`. So we need to tell it to use Java 8. We do this by updating the `android` section.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
  }
  // add the following
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: I have removed it and now I get this error.                                                                                                     
                                                                               Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\lottie-2.5.6.aar\add5db5cebf38e2804a0cb857e5cf364\jars\classes.jar

Comment: Don't post large amounts of code in comments, it is impossible to read. Try disabling instant run if you have it enabled.

`Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Disable `

Comment: Yeah disabled it.

Comment: Is there any other fix?

Comment: Which version of `lottie-react-native` are you using in your `package.json`?

Comment: I have this in package.json "lottie-react-native": "^2.5.8"